# Where does xcode-select store information

Tags: xcode

I am writing a tool, that runs clang from Xcode path. This tool gets location of Xcode by running /usr/bin/xcode-select, but I want to remake it so that it reads Xcode location directly from disk instead of running xcode-select. I tried to debug xcode-select (which is a symlink to xcrun), but didn't manage to find how it stores/reads location of Xcode (does it stores it in environment or files?). If you know how to get location of Xcode without running xcode-select (and xcrun), please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used [dtruss](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html) command to print all open syscalls of xcode-select.

```
dtruss -f -t open xcode-select -print-path
```

It tries to read /usr/share/xcode-select/xcode_dir_path and get Xcode location from there. If it does not exist, it takes the default Xcode location, which is /Applications/Xcode.app/.

Comment: Wow. It is good to know that xcode-select used to be tracable with dtruss. On a modern macOS, the above command does not work but give an error:
```
dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available
dtrace: failed to initialize dtrace: DTrace requires additional privileges
```

Comment: @cxwangyi you can disable system integrity before running this command. Reenable it afterwards.

Comment: Ah. I see. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection. Thank you @Elviss Strazdins!

Answer (score 4):

As of Xcode 6, the location is a symlink at `/var/db/xcode_select_link`. You can output the target of the link to your terminal with the command `readlink /var/db/xcode_select_link`. If there is no link (eg, you run `xcode-select --reset`), the default xcode installation is used.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @chouaib I respectfully disagree.  The title of the question is "Where does xcode-select store information".  The OP states "I tried to debug xcode-select (which is a symlink to xcrun), but didn't manage to find how it stores/reads location of Xcode (does it stores it in environment or files?)."  I answered the question, though I've edited to my answer to clarify the file I was referring to is a symbolic link.  xcode-select creates the symlink for redirection and removes on `--reset`.  You can read the link with `readlink`.

Answer (score 3):

With NSWorkspace you can do a:

```
[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]fullPathForApplication:@"Xcode"];
```

which returns `/Applications/Xcode.app` when it's installed in the default location.

```
// …or, as I have seen in the documentation, there's also
- (NSURL *)URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:(NSString *)bundleIdentifier
// which returns the URL for the application with the specified identifier.
```

Comment: The problem is, that I don't know the name of the app (it can be Xcode2 or anything else). If user has multiple versions of Xcode, he can xcode-select -switch to another location.