# Could not find path to Xcode by symlinks located in /var/db/xcode_select_link, or /usr/share/xcode-select/xcode_dir_link

Tags: php, xcode, appium, appium-ios

I am trying to setup appium for ios app testing using php, but when I am tring to execute test scripts

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit SimpleTest.php --verbose
```

I am getting this error:

> PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find path to Xcode by symlinks located in /var/db/xcode_select_link, or /usr/share/xcode-select/xcode_dir_link"

Tried this `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` but that didn't work.

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 1):

As already mention in this post:[where-does-xcode-select-store-information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609738/where-does-xcode-select-store-information)
The comment from [0x1mason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/347155/0x1mason) helped me in my case with 2 Xcode-Versions. I used the following commands in Terminal:

1. readlink /var/db/xcode_select_link --> Checked the path
2. xcode-select --reset
3. restart MacOS
4. checked again with readlink /var/db/xcode_select_link in Terminal

Hope it helps you too.