# pod install failed on macOS Big sur

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, development-environment, macos-big-sur

I am pretty new to macOS and recently shift to macOS from windows, I started to working on react-native app and when I try `react-native run-ios` it gives me below error

```
error Could not find "Podfile.lock" at /Users/saniranimantha/Documents/Learning/albums/ios/Podfile.lock. Did you run "pod install" in iOS directory?
info Found Xcode project "albums.xcodeproj"
info Launching iPhone 11 (iOS 14.3)
info Building (using "xcodebuild -project albums.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme albums -destination id=FE71292F-36FA-4226-A8E5-B4EF4E8B625D")
(node:726) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening albums.xcodeproj. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

when I search for the reason to this error, I found out that I need to run `pod install` command, when I try that, it gives me another error. I tried several suggestions from stack-overflow & git, but still no luck. I did install `cocoapod`. I searched for a similar issue, but couldn't find anything. That's why I decided to post it here for an answer. if anyone can help me here, that would be really great.

**my OS is macOS Big Sur (v11.1)**

this is my podfile

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'albums' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'albumsTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'albums-tvOS' do
  # Pods for albums-tvOS

  target 'albums-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

this is the error I get on `pod install`

````
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.10.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.arm64e-darwin20]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : macOS 11.1 (20C69)
       Xcode : 12.3 (12C33)
         Git : git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : 
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'albums' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'albumsTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'albums-tvOS' do
  # Pods for albums-tvOS

  target 'albums-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

### Error

```
LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:74:in `cdn_url?'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:36:in `create_source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:21:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1073:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
````

**EDIT**
for a one react-native project(newly created one) @Leri Gogsadze's answer was working. I cloned a repo which is already developed react-native app, and had the same issue, in that project, I tried the solution suggested by @Leri but did't work `react-native run-ios` build failed, then I tried `pod update` command and it now gives me the below error.

````
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `GregMobileSecondPhase`: BVLinearGradient, RNCAsyncStorage, RNCMaskedView, RNCPicker, RNDateTimePicker, RNDeviceInfo, RNFBApp, RNFBMessaging, RNFS, RNGestureHandler, RNImageCropPicker, RNKeychain, RNReanimated, RNSVG, RNScreens, RNVectorIcons, ReactNativeART, react-native-add-calendar-event, react-native-document-picker, react-native-fbsdk, react-native-geolocation-service, react-native-maps, react-native-safe-area-context, react-native-slider, react-native-viewpager, react-native-webview, and rn-range-slider
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod update
```

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.10.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.arm64e-darwin20]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : macOS 11.1 (20C69)
       Xcode : 12.3 (12C33)
         Git : git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'GregMobileSecondPhase' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'


  target 'GregMobileSecondPhaseTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'GregMobileSecondPhase-tvOS' do
  # Pods for GregMobileSecondPhase-tvOS

  target 'GregMobileSecondPhase-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

### Error

```
LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:78:in `deprecated_local_podspecs'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:60:in `preheat_existing_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:257:in `update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:135:in `block (3 levels) in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:134:in `block (2 levels) in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:133:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:133:in `block in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:131:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:131:in `update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:145:in `block in update_repositories'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:143:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:143:in `update_repositories'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:235:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command/update.rb:63:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+missing+compatible+arch+in+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle+-+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.14.2%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new

[!] NPM package '@react-native-firebase/messaging' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v10.3.0 but found v10.2.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.
saniranimantha@Saniras-MBP ios % ~
````

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Seems it's related to Ruby ffi. Run the following commands:

- `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
- `arch -x86_64 pod install`

Comment: seems this works. But got one question, I saw this ```arch -x86_64``` thing everywhere, can you explain what it is exactly? why do we use that part?

Comment: `x86_64 is the 64-bit version of the OS`. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) article.

Comment: And Ruby-FFI is a gem for programmatically loading dynamically-linked native libraries, binding functions within them, and calling those functions from Ruby code.

Comment: yes I know that x86_64 refers to 64 bit version of the OS, I asked why do we use ```arch -x86_64``` thing, I saw it in several places, where direct command does not works, they suggested to use this part before the command. I'm curios about that. Thanks BTW for the insight though

Comment: for a one react-native project, this works, but I have another one now, it's failing because of the same reason. I tried those command, but still there's an error with ```react-native run-ios```

Comment: yup, may be it's not related to pod install, it's working now, but the ```react-native run-ios``` keep getting failed. so I tried ```pod updat``` it's getting failed for the same reason, compatible issue in ffi

Comment: will update the question, it's too long to comment

Comment: `sudo gem install ffi` try this without `arch`

Comment: tried that already, no luck, can't think what goes wrong here

Comment: ```arch -x86_64 pod update``` give the same error

Comment: Try with `sudo`

Comment: Pod installed with this command successfully. But when I tried to run application "Module not found" error started.So, I unable to run the application.

Comment: Did you restart dev server?

Comment: https://github.com/segiddins/ffi/pull/1 This is the PR to update ffi to apple silicon if you want to keep track of the progress.

Comment: I'm getting same error. When I tried your solution now it gives `[!] Couldn't determine repo type for URL: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/: Invalid ABI specified.` Did you faced with this problem? @LeriGogsadze

Comment: @AlexanderChef No but try these commands: `pod repo remove trunk` and then `pod install` again

Comment: I tried but still getting same error :/ @LeriGogsadze

Comment: I had a previous swift project in Xcode that was throwing this error once I downloaded it onto a MacBook pro M1 chip. These commands fixed the issue.

Answer (score 31):

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Then

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

This works for Apple M1 Chip. Confirmed.

Comment: Yes! This sure worked for my MacBook Pro 2021 M1 chip. Thanks Majid

Comment: worked for  Macbook Pro M2 as well. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

on Apple Silicon and MacOS Big Sur, I fixed it this way and it worked

1. Locate Terminal.app in Finder
2. Right-click and choose *Get Info*
3. Check the *Open using Rosetta*
4. Quit Terminal app and run it again
5. Run *sudo gem install ffi*
6. Run *pod install*

See detail at: https://armen-mkrtchian.medium.com/run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-and-macos-big-sur-developer-transition-kit-b62acffc1387

Answer (score 6):

or we can do it, it works for me:

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

brew install cocoapods

Comment: But Pod Gen command will not work since it needs cocopods-Generate which not in brew formula

Answer (score 2):

for homebrew users

step 1 `brew install cocoapods`
step 2 `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
step 3 `arch -x86_64 pod install`

fixed my issue

and if problem is still persisting you might have installed node.js with other platform rather than homebrew

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same issue, while doing `pod install` in React native project, running on M1 chip MacBook. This helped me to resolve the issue.

Open the rosetta terminal and type below commands.

```
-- sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos
```

Inside the ios folder of the project, type the below command :

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Below are the steps i followed. The issue got resolved.

1. Install ruby in homebrew (brew install ruby)
2. Add export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:$PATH to your .zshrc
3. source ~/.zshrc
4. sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
5. pod setup
6. arch -arm64 gem install ffi
7. change to project directory inside ios folder execute the following command
   **arch -arm64 pod install**

Comment: F**cking save my day. Love you and thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was **recloning the repo** and starting all over.

You can also try to **update cocoapods**, **last case update also Xcode** and re-cloning the repo.

There is currently missmatch regarding the pods, libraries, dependencies and Xcode, for example the Firebase SDK that you also use is updating frequently.

My setup:
Xcode 12.4
Mac M1
react-native 63.4

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue then while checking pod version

```
pod --version
```

this was part of the output

```
Ignoring ffi-1.16.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.16.3
.
.
1.15.0
```

then I run the following

```
sudo gem pristine ffi --version 1.16.3
```

and finally run `pod install` successfully