# Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, react-native, cocoapods

I am getting this when trying to install React Native for MacOS.

```
$ npx react-native init myproject
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libc++.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (10.15) than being linked (10.13)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libunwind.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (10.15) than being linked (10.13)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libunwind.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (10.15) than being linked (10.13)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libc++.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (10.15) than being linked (10.13)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libunwind.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (10.15) than being linked (10.13)
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libunwind.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (10.15) than being linked (10.13)
...
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./myproject/ios && pod install".
CocoaPods documentation: https://cocoapods.org/
$ cd ./myproject/ios && pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.5)
Installing CocoaLibEvent (1.0.0)
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing FBLazyVector (0.63.4)
Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.63.4)
Installing Flipper (0.54.0)
Installing Flipper-DoubleConversion (1.1.7)
Installing Flipper-Folly (2.3.0)
Installing Flipper-Glog (0.3.6)
[!] /bin/bash -c
set -e
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

# Fix build for tvOS
cat << EOF >> src/config.h
/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif
/* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
#if TARGET_OS_TV
#undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
#undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
#undef OS_MACOSX
#endif
/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk
checking whether the C compiler works... no
/Users/lancepollard/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/lancepollard/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/lancepollard/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

A snippet from `config.log` says:

```
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:3685: $? = 1
configure:3674: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
clang: error: no input files
configure:3685: $? = 1
configure:3705: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3727: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.3.sdk  -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib conftest.c  >&5
ld: in '/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libunwind.dylib', building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:3731: $? = 1
configure:3769: result: no
configure: failed program was:
...
configure: exit 77
```

My Mac version is Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2). XCode is version 12.

[image]

I tried everything from [React-Native: Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934022/react-native-error-failed-to-install-cocoapods-dependencies-for-ios-project-w), but nothing worked. I invoked `brew install cocoapods` as well.

Any ideas how to get past this? Could it be something to do with the fact that I have a `node_modules` folder higher up in the directory structure (above where I am running the commands)? I don't know what this error means.

Here is also output from the `missing` command:

```
$ /Users/lancepollard/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing --help
/Users/lancepollard/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing [OPTION]... PROGRAM [ARGUMENT]...

Handle `PROGRAM [ARGUMENT]...' for when PROGRAM is missing, or return an
error status if there is no known handling for PROGRAM.

Options:
  -h, --help      display this help and exit
  -v, --version   output version information and exit
  --run           try to run the given command, and emulate it if it fails

Supported PROGRAM values:
  aclocal      touch file `aclocal.m4'
  autoconf     touch file `configure'
  autoheader   touch file `config.h.in'
  autom4te     touch the output file, or create a stub one
  automake     touch all `Makefile.in' files
  bison        create `y.tab.[ch]', if possible, from existing .[ch]
  flex         create `lex.yy.c', if possible, from existing .c
  help2man     touch the output file
  lex          create `lex.yy.c', if possible, from existing .c
  makeinfo     touch the output file
  tar          try tar, gnutar, gtar, then tar without non-portable flags
  yacc         create `y.tab.[ch]', if possible, from existing .[ch]

Send bug reports to <bug-automake@gnu.org>.
```

Comment: I have no clue. Just guessing: Curious to know what you got from running `/Users/lancepollard/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing --help`? Can you add that into your question? And just because you said  _Could it be something to do with the fact that I have a node_modules folder higher up in the directory structure_ I suggest you try doing this in another directory which that is no the case and see if it works. 

If it does then I'd inspect to see what's different for the `gem env` between where it works and where it doesn't...

Comment: Updated the the output of the `missing` command. Running outside of the directory didn't help :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Removing `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25561) in my bashrc fixed it for me!

Comment: What are those exactly? And why where they added? Can you explain a bi?

Comment: These were added in my case for a completely unrelated LLVM usage for some reason. I _may_ have added these at some point months ago when playing with LLVM, I'm not sure. But they caused the `Flipper-Glog` to fail installing for some unknown reason. Thankfully someone already figured this out, I would have never figured that out haha. I don't even know what those variables do but I think they are generic clang or gcc compiler variables.

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me as well. It was because of old CocoaPods version. I used version 1.8.0. After upgrading it to version 1.10.1, the error was gone

Answer (score 1):

## I was able to fix my error by upgrading:

1. MacOS to Monterrey 12.0.1
2. XCODE to 13.1
3. Setting the location on XCODE
4. Install additional tools when prompted the first time you open XCODE

### Here is my RN current configuration

```
react-native info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: macOS 12.0.1
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Memory: 104.32 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.15.4 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.10 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2021.10.18.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.0.1, iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 29, 30
      Build Tools: 28.0.0, 28.0.1, 28.0.2, 28.0.3, 29.0.0, 29.0.1, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.0, 30.0.1, 30.0.2, 30.0.3
      System Images: android-29 | Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.7199119
    Xcode: 13.1/13A1030d - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: javac 16 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.18 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.66.0 => 0.66.0 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

### HERE IS MY ORIGINAL ERROR - when unable to install PODs

```
Installing Flipper-Glog (0.3.6)
[!] /usr/local/bin/bash -c 
set -e
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

# Fix build for tvOS
cat << EOF >> src/config.h
/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif
/* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
#if TARGET_OS_TV
#undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
#undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
#undef OS_MACOSX
#endif
/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/local/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/local/bin/gmkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Applications/Xcode 12.5.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode 12.5.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk
checking whether the C compiler works... no
/Users/jonathans/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/jonathans/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/jonathans/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAYsL.png
```

Issue seems to be that since the IOS 15 release, RN, simulators and XCODE need to be upgraded together.

#### After I upgraded MacOS & XCODE, then pods installed and was able run the simulator properly.