# Error: Failed to install Cocoapods dependencies

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)

```
Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./cocococo/ios && pod install".
CocoaPods documentation: https://cocoapods.org/
```

Comment: `brew install cocoapods` and then `cd iOS && pod install && cd ..`

Comment: it's didn't solved yet..... thanks for your help.

Comment: Please check if any answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934022/react-native-error-failed-to-install-cocoapods-dependencies-for-ios-project-w) question helps you.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 13.0? If yes, then you need to change the project to Xcode 12.0 compatible. Visit this link: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10713#issuecomment-865145924