# Can't install Cocoapods on M1 Silicon when setting up React Native environment

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods

I'm not able to install Cocoapods in context with setting up React Native environment on my M1 Silicon due to below error.

M1, 2020
MacOs Big Sur 11.3.1
X-Code 13.2.1

```
jonas@Air-von-Jonas ~ % sudo gem install cocoapods
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20220424-55001-og2rl2.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.
```

I already tried all of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1), [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934022/react-native-error-failed-to-install-cocoapods-dependencies-for-ios-project-w), the [official cocoapod guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting#installing-cocoapods) and also tried the official [React-Native hints](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).

Answer (score 0):

- In the first step, you must look for the terminal in the finder.
- After this, you need to right-click on the terminal and then click on “get info”, and after this, you are required to check open using Rosetta, which you can easily find under the general menu.
- After the above step, you should open the terminal, and then you need
  to type **sudo gem install ffi**
- Then you are required to install the CocoaPods with the sudo gem
  install cocoapods
- Once you have successfully installed the CocoaPods, you need to
  uncheck the box appearing on your screen with the Open using Rosetta,
  and it will again start working.
- Then you can visit your project directory and work again.